# SQL Update Command within a PHP Do While Loop

Tags: php, sql, do-while

I have a SQL database called projects with the fields post_id, feature_image, order, and landscape. Landscape is for all intensive purposes a category.

As a broad overview of the function I am trying to get to;

Page loads
1 recordset takes all of categorized post_id# (1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 12...etc) and renumbers specifically 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... etc
That renumbering for each post_id# would then send an update to the SQL in a field that is provided called order which would take those values.
Then 2 recordsets (one odd, one even) load not the post_id but the order# and all the relevant information (in this case a featured image) and output on the screen two columns of pictures that are in correct order based on whatever category is loaded.

I understand I can order by the post_id, that **isnt** the issue. I specifically want the ability to have all of the numbers reordered to the numbers exactly 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc on page load.

I only posted the first part of the if statement because I know it isnt that part of it that is messing up. Everything works with the variables etc, the only issue is I cant get the darn variable to be sent to the database under the field order. I've worked for far too long on this and have no idea what I am doing wrong at this point. No errors, just the order field stays NULL in the database.

I will throw a tickertape parade for anyone who can fix this code or tell me why I am doing everything bass-ackwards and there is a better way to do so.

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_connTest, $connTest) or die("cannot select database");
$query_RS_Odd = "SELECT projects.post_id, projects.feature_image, projects.`order` FROM projects WHERE projects.landscape = 'landscape'";
$RS_Odd = mysql_query($query_RS_Odd, $connTest) or die(mysql_error());
$row_RS_Odd = mysql_fetch_assoc($RS_Odd);
$totalRows_RS_Odd = mysql_num_rows($RS_Odd);
?>

<?php do {
if ($row_RS_Odd['post_id'] == 1){ 
    $resort_next = 1;
    mysql_query("UPDATE projects SET order=".$resort_next." WHERE post_id=".$row_RS_Odd['post_id']."");
    echo $row_RS_Odd['post_id'];
    echo $resort_next;
}
else {
echo 'No records found';
}
 } while ($row_RS_Odd = mysql_fetch_assoc($RS_Odd)); ?>
```

Comment: It keeps updating `post_id` 1, is that expected?

Comment: Yes, in this simple case it should as in other else if statements (not included in this) I have it go on for other ones. I kept it simple just to see if it would update the SQL table at all. Unfortunately post_id #1 still has the field order remaining as NULL or 0

Comment: Also, as assisted below I have found out that the SQL query is indeed having an error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''modified'=1 WHERE post_id=1' at line 1" but I am not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Although you have quoted the mysql reserved `order` word correctly in you `select` statement, you have forgotten to do that in the `update` statement:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE projects SET order=".$resort_next." WHERE post_id=".$row_RS_Odd['post_id']."");
```

should be:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE projects SET `order`=".$resort_next." WHERE post_id=".$row_RS_Odd['post_id']."");
```

Note that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and you should really switch to PDO / mysqli and prepared statements.

Comment: I've been told I should switch; so do I just switch to mysqli_query("...."); ?

Also, I did try changing that to 'order' but unfortunately that didnt fix the issue. Still not sending the variable to that field. Is there something about it being in the loop that doesnt allow it?

Comment: @Tysons Engineer I would recommend prepared statements and PDO but there is a bit more to it than just changing the function names. And your current sql query is nothing more than just `UPDATE projects SET order=1 WHERE post_id=1`. Are you sure that is not happening?

Comment: Yea absolutely. I simplified it to see where the issue was (in a separate version I had additional else if that would go on to #2, 3, 4, etc) and I verified that the variables are changing by echoing the post_id next to the $resort_next in a table for each row.

This echos correctly on the screen as 1 and 1. But when I go to my database order field remains = 0 for post_id #1

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills as to why it wont update my field, I tried everything with different SQL things for variables etc.

Comment: For reference I have the order field as an integer with length 100, default set to NULL. Variations included I tried this as a string, tried it as a var. I also had it at one point not set to default to NULL. Clearly I am very confused

Comment: @Tysons Engineer You should start by adding proper error handling. Check out the value of `mysql_error()` after your failing query.

Comment: ok now I see after echo mysql_error(); I got an error in the output as follow "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''order'=1 WHERE post_id=1' at line 1"

Comment: @Tysons Engineer There is no `modified` in your code... What is the complete sql statement?

Comment: Sorry sorry, I changed it from order after your original statement to make sure it wasnt because I was using the SQL order word for another use. I can turn it back to order if its confusing

Comment: Alright all, sorry for my idiocy.

I simply changed the field name to modified and then removed the single quotes and it worked. I can't believe that stumped me for this long. Note to everyone out there, DONT USE SPECIAL WORDS EVER FOR ANYTHING